# How do I point my Heroku OAuth/RoR app to curl-ca-bundle.crt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, heroku, facebook-oauth

I am using Oauth to connect to facebook, and it works fine for local development.

I want to run this on Heroku however, and there I get this error:

```
2012-06-14T15:50:16+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - Certificate file "/opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt" does not exist!):
2012-06-14T15:50:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/sharing_controller.rb:138:in `facebook_callback'
```

I have configured the SSL endpoint in Heroku but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out -

I had to change the Koala cert path parameter:

Old:
    Koala.http_service.ca_file = '/opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt'

New:
    Koala.http_service.ca_file = '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'

Comment: Hey, glad it worked :) You should mark your answer as Accepted.